# SharePoint 2010 Authentication Using HttpClient

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dotnet-httpclient

I need to authenticate with a SharePoint 2010 based site for making subsequent authenticated web service calls to that web site. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate with a SharePoint 2010 site using SharePoint SOAP services like the following:

```
public Cookie GetSharePoint2010AuthenticationCookie(string url, string userName, string password, string proxyIp)
{
    var content = new StringContent(
        $@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
            <soap:Body>
            <Login xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
                <username>{userName}</username>
                <password>{password}</password>
            </Login>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>",
        Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer(1);
    var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
    {
        Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
    };
    
    var siteUri = new Uri(url);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(proxyIp))
    {
        // In case we are using a proxy IP
        // (we are calling a specific machine at a specific IP).
        client.BaseAddress =
            new Uri($"https://{proxyIp}:443");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", siteUri.Host);
        client.AllowAutoRedirect true;
    }
    else
    {
        client.BaseAddress = siteUri;
    }

    // Make the request.
    var result = client.PostAsync("/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx", content)
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
    var cookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(client.BaseAddress)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK
        || cookie == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to generate cookie");
    }

    return cookie;
}
```